# Select text from file

Tags: java, string, file, select, words

I have a program that should select phone numbers and people names, surnames and their university titles from an html file.

The problem is that when I read the file line by line, the program is not working.

```
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.html"))) {
     String inputLine;
     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
         Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\+\\d{3}) (\\d{5})...(\\d{4})\\D+\\d+\\\">(.*)<").matcher(inputLine);
         while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.print(matcher.group(1)+" "+matcher.group(2)+" ("+matcher.group(3)+") "+matcher.group(4)+"\n");
         }
      }
    }
```

Here is a some text example i have in html:

```
+123 48535<b>3597</b>   </td>
<td>
    <a href="/abcd/315">prof. Dr. Ing. Name Surname</a>
</td>
<td>
<tr>
<th class="function-title" colspan="4">some_function</th>
</tr>       
<tr>
<td>
  +123 48535<b>3656</b>   </td>
<td>
    <a href="/zamestnanec/167">doc. PhDr. Name2 Surname2, Ph.D.</a>
</td>
```

The expected output look like this:

`+123 48535 (3597) prof. Dr. Ing. Name Surname
 +123 48535 (3656) doc. PhDr. Name2 Surname2, Ph.D.`

Code work as expected, if for example I have a `String inputLine = "same text that was in html file"` but when I read from the file, it's not working, all I get is nothing :(

Comment: If the file is HTML, use an HTML parser; like JSoup for instance. It will make your job much easier.